# Asynctask stopped displaying data in textView when the activity is reopened

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i am trying to make an application where asynctask is used to continously update a textview in my main interface. There is another button  which opens another activity. When i start the application, the asyntask starts and displays data to the textview but when i click on the other button to open another activity and click on back button to return to the previous activity where the aysnctask was running, it stopped displaying data to the textview.

Could you help mem with this problem or suggest alternative ways. Thank you.

Code for MainActivity:

```
Button about; 
TextView tempData;
Context context = this;
AllSensorData sensorData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.hAbout);

    tempData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempData);

    sensorData=new AllSensorData(tempData,getApplicationContext());
    sensorData.execute("http://192.168.1.177/");


    about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
     {  
         @Override  
         public void onClick(View v)  
         {  
             Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutActivity.class);               
             startActivity(i);
         }  
     });
```

Code for aynctask class:

```
public class AllSensorData extends AsyncTask<String, byte[], String>{

    TextView temp;

    Context context;

    public AllSensorData(TextView temp,Context context) {
            this.temp=temp;
            this.context=context;
    }


    InputStream nis;
    OutputStream nos;
    BufferedReader in;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlconn=null;
    InputStreamReader isn;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response;
            try {


                //this method is working for data only
                while(true){//while connected
            HttpGet httpget =new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.177/");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String msgFromServer = in.readLine();//read the lines coming from the socket
                byte[] theByteArray = msgFromServer.getBytes();//store the bytes in an array
                publishProgress(theByteArray);//update the publishProgress


                    if(isCancelled()){
                        break;
                    }
                }


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        return null;
    }

     private boolean alreadyDisplayedNotification = false;

     private boolean already =false ;

     protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         String command=new String(values[0]);//get the String from the recieved bytes
         String[] parts= command.split(",");
         String part1=parts[0];


         temp.setText(part1);

     }
}
```

Comment: add your textview update code in onResume method;

Comment: read about activity life cycle for it, and show to save state of activities

Comment: I used the onResumed method and still the asynctask is not displaying the data when reopened the activity

Answer (score 0):

Read about the activity state saving and recreation of Activity

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: sir , the reopened activity does not display anything in the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [save instance state](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) to understand why your value in text is not showing

put your "refresh" code inside of onStart() instead of onResume(). onStart() gets "Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user."

Go through [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: no i am no been able to make it display the data in the textview.

Comment: okay. as in my answer you have to save value of textview and then on activity OnRestart()  set it again @akshay270494

Comment: i refer to your link and tried to implement it in my code.. still no good result. I do not know what to save as i am using asynctask onprogressupdate method to keep updating the textviews

Comment: you have to save value of textview and store to some variable than on activity onRestart() , set that value again@akshay270494